# Is it true that $\frac{\ln(a)}2=\ln(\sqrt{a})$ for $a>0$? In particular, is $\frac{\ln(2)}{2}=\ln(\sqrt2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I believe the following two identities are correct. For some reason, they look wrong to me. Are they?
$$ \frac{ \ln \left( 2 \right) } { 2 } = \ln( \sqrt{2} ) $$
$$ \frac{ \ln \left( a \right) } { 2 } = \ln( \sqrt{a} ) $$
The second one being valid for all $a > 0$.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you told us what your reason for thinking the identities are wrong is. To check the identities, note that $x = y$ iff $e^x = e^y$.

Comment: No they aren't. $c\ln x$ is always equal to $\ln (x^c)$ where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: I guess they look wrong to me because we are dividing by $2$ rather than multiplying by $2$. Of course dividing by $2$ is the same as multiplying by $\frac{1}{2}$. I am glad to hear that they are right.

Comment: In general $ln(ab)=ln(a)+ln(b)$, so $ln(x)=ln(\sqrt{x})+ln(\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: This is simply the identity $\ln a^b = b\ln a$ and the definition $\sqrt a = a^{\frac 12}$.  It's a bit nice to know when we were defining things we took care that they made sense and were consistant and we weren't just pulling things out of muck.

Comment: @Bob: you may find it helpful to think of $\sqrt{2}$ as $2^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ as $2^{-1}$ so that the division is confined to the exponents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both correct. To prove them, use the [logarithm property](http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/expolog_1.htm#properties) $\ln\left(a^b\right)=b\ln(a)$, for $a\gt0$.

This can be rewritten as
$$b\ln(a)=\ln\left(a^b\right),\;\;\;\text{for }a\gt0$$
$\frac{\ln(a)}{2}$ can be written as $\frac12\ln(a)$, and $a^{(1/2)}\equiv\sqrt a$.

You can finish it from here.

Answer (score 2):

These are in fact correct. Notice it comes from the fact that

$${e^{\ln(\sqrt{a})}=a^{\frac{1}{2}}=(e^{\ln(a)})^{\frac{1}{2}}=e^{\frac{\ln(a)}{2}}}$$

Now, since ${e^{x}}$ is bijective (and hence injective) on ${\mathbb{R}}$, then

$${e^x=e^y \Leftrightarrow x=y}$$

And so finally

$${\ln(\sqrt{a}) = \frac{\ln(a)}{2}}$$

Comment: Your answer is among the clearest.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a logarithm property.

For all $a \geq 0$ and for all $c > 0$, this property holds:

$$ \log_c(a^b) = b\log_c(a) $$

This property is known as the “logarithm power rule”.

Your question is about the specific case where $b = \dfrac12$. You can see that it’s true by rewriting $\ln(\sqrt{a})$ and then using the logarithm property, like this:

$$\ln(\sqrt{a}) = \ln\left(a^{1/2}\right) = \frac{\ln a}{2}$$

The proof of the rule is as follows:

$$ a = c^{\log_c(a)}  \tag*{Exponentiation as inverse of $\log$} $$
$$ a^b = \left(c^{\log_c(a)}\right)^b  \tag*{Each side to the power of $b$}$$
$$ a^b = c^{b\log_c(a)}  \tag*{Power rule of exponentiation}$$
$$ \log_c\left(a^b\right) = \log_c\left(c^{b\log_c(a)}\right)  \tag*{$\log_c$ of both sides} $$
$$ \boxed{\log_c\left(a^b\right) = b\log_c(a)}  \tag*{$\log$ as inverse of exponentiation} $$

Answer (score 0):

$\ln x = \log_e x$. Multiply $\frac{\ln(a)}{2} = \ln(\sqrt{a})$ by $2$ to get $\ln(a) = 2\ln(\sqrt{a})$, and by the log rule $x\log_a b = \log_a b^x$, we get $\ln(a) = \ln(\sqrt{a}^2)$, which is obviously true.

-FruDe

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict $\log$ function to real numbers, then it is defined for all arguments $ >0$. Also, square root of a positive number is positive. Hence, $\log \sqrt{a}$ exists as long as $a>0$